# how do i calculate Qty To Be Issued in List collection

Tags: c#

```
List<Serials> serials = new List<Serials>
{
    new Serials { Id = 1, Qty = 30, SRNo = "SR-001" },
    new Serials { Id = 2, Qty = 70, SRNo = "SR-002" }
};

decimal? QtyToBeIssued = 50;

// i tried however i did not get it in foreach loop
foreach (var item in serials)
{
    decimal? ToBeIssued = 0;
    if (QtyToBeIssued > item.Qty)
    {
        ToBeIssued = item.Qty;
        item.Qty = item.Qty - ToBeIssued;
    }         
}
```

`QtyToBeIssued = 50` and serials collection's has first object has 30 i.e need to subtract `30 - 30 = 0`  and remaining `qty= 20`
and that remaining 20 subtract from 2nd collection i.e 70-20 = 50 
so my object collection will be looks like below after calculation 
.i need to issue 30 from 1st record and 20 from second record.

```
Id = 1, Qty = 0, SRNo = "SR-001"
Id = 2, Qty = 50, SRNo = "SR-002"
```

Comment: You're never changing `QtyToBeIssued` based on `ToBeIssued`, and you're not doing *anything* if the current item's quantity is more than `QtyToBeIssued`.

Comment: Add another property to your class Serial so you have both Qty and QtyToBeIssued.

Comment: You could also add a break in order to not iterate all the stock when the quantity is small. Imagine a large stock, you want to windraw only one item. Do you really have to continue the foreach on all the serials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the bellow code

```
List<Serials> serials = new List<Serials>
        {
            new Serials { Id = 1, Qty = 30, SRNo = "SR-001" },
            new Serials { Id = 2, Qty = 70, SRNo = "SR-002" }
        };

int QtyToBeIssued = 50;


foreach (var item in serials)
{
     int ToBeIssued = 0;
     if (QtyToBeIssued > 0)
     {
         var temp = item.Qty - QtyToBeIssued < 0 ? 0 : item.Qty - QtyToBeIssued;
         QtyToBeIssued -= item.Qty;
         item.Qty = temp;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the QtyToBeIssued in your for loop. To match the description of your code, you have to also cover the case when QtyToBeIssued is not enough for your item.

So I would do something like this:

```
List<Serials> serials = new List<Serials>
{
    new Serials { Id = 1, Qty = 30, SRNo = "SR-001" },
    new Serials { Id = 2, Qty = 70, SRNo = "SR-002" }
};

decimal? QtyToBeIssued = 50;


foreach (var item in serials)
{
    decimal? ToBeIssued = 0;
    if (QtyToBeIssued > item.Qty)
    {
        ToBeIssued = item.Qty;
    }         
    else // QtyTyBeIssued <= item.Qty
    {
        ToBeIssued = QtyToBeIssued;
    }
    item.Qty = item.Qty - ToBeIssued;
    QtyToBeIssued = QtyToBeIssued - ToBeIssued;
}
```

Edit: and for shorter code:

```
foreach (var item in serials)
{
    decimal? ToBeIssued = Math.Min(item.Qty, QtyToBeIssued);
    item.Qty -= ToBeIssued;
    QtyToBeIssued -= ToBeIssued;
}
```

Comment: The shorter code is the correct answer. it may need a `if(QtyToBeIssued <= 0) break;
   if(item.Qty>=0) continue;` at the start of the foreach. to Clarify the fact that we don't want to loop on all the stock if we need nothing and we won't do math on empty stock.

Comment: i want to loop through all rows in collection and your solution works fine thanks @Sokopa

Comment: yes  i was not modifying the QtyToBeIssued in your for loop and that piece of logic i didn't get it thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by this way, live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FOKzTx)

```
var count = 0;
serials.ForEach(p =>
{
    count++;
    if (QtyToBeIssued >= p.Qty)
    {
        QtyToBeIssued -= p.Qty;
        p.Qty = 0;
    }
    if (count == serials.Count)
    {
        p.Qty -= (int)QtyToBeIssued;
    }
});
```

Out put:

> ID: 1 Qty: 0 SRNo: SR-001
>
> ID: 2 Qty: 50 SRNo: SR-002

Comment: Don't mention it. It's my pleasure. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        List<Serials> serials = new List<Serials>
        {
            new Serials { Id = 1, Qty = 30, SRNo = "SR-001" },
            new Serials { Id = 2, Qty = 70, SRNo = "SR-002" }
        };

        decimal? QtyToBeIssued = 50;

        foreach (var item in serials)
        {
            if (QtyToBeIssued > item.Qty)
            {
                QtyToBeIssued = QtyToBeIssued - item.Qty;
                item.Qty = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Qty = item.Qty - QtyToBeIssued;
            }
        }
```